# jQuery .push on serializeArray()

Tags: jquery

So I am using serializeArray() to get the data from a form, I also have a bootstrap dropdown menu where I need the 'data-id' attribute to be posted also. Sure I have used push for this before... When posted in the console the post var name is undefined and has no value... Here is my code:

```
$('#changeUserInfo').unbind().bind('submit', function(){

    var location = $('[data-dropper="location-dropdown"]').attr('location-id');

    var newData = $('[data-changeuser="info"]:last').serializeArray();

    newData.push({ location : location });

    $.post(URL+'manage_accounts/update_user', newData, function(e){
        if(e.status){
            $('.featherlight').append('<div class="success_box"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span><p>User updated</p></div>');
            window.location = window.location.href.split('#')[0];
        } else {
            $('.featherlight').append('<div class="fail_box"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"></span><p>Failed to update user</p></div>');
            $('.fail_box').delay(800).fadeOut();
        }
    },'json');

    return false;

});
```

Thanks

Comment: there is no `var name` in code shown. What exactly is undefined? Please clarify what the  problem is

Comment: the location var, should be added onto the end of the newData array, instead in console I can see a post var named undefined with no value..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`serializeArray()` produces array of objects like the following (copied from docs)

```
[
{name: "a", value: "1"},
{name: "b", value: "2"}
]
```

to match that format you need to do:

```
newData.push({ name: 'location', value: location });
```

Reference: **[serializeArray() docs](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/)**